# Launching asynchronous, Node.js-like HTTP request in Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I've previously written applications, specifically data scrapers, in Node.js.  These types of applications had no web front end, but were merely processes timed with cron jobs to asynchronously make a number of possibly complicated HTTP GET requests to pull web pages, and then scrape and store the data from the results.

A sample of a function I might write would be this:

```js
// Node.js

var request = require("request");

function scrapeEverything() {
    var listOfIds = [23423, 52356, 63462, 34673, 67436];

    for (var i = 0; i < listOfIds.length; i++) {
        request({uri: "http://mydatasite.com/?data_id = " + listOfIds[i]},
                function(err, response, body) {
                     var jsonobj = JSON.parse(body);
                      storeMyData(jsonobj);
                });
    }
}
```

This function loops through the IDs and makes a bunch of asynchronous GET requests, from which it then stores the data.

I'm now writing a scraper in Python and attempting to do the same thing using Tornado, but everything I see in the documentation refers to Tornado acting as a web server, which is not what I'm looking for.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: For anyone who comes across this question later, I ended up using `Twisted` instead, (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which is a great async model for Python programs, and though it has a learning curve, I was able to do it without having to work around a structure meant for web servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more involved answer than I thought I would throw together, but it's a quick demo of how to use Tornado ioloop and AsyncHTTPClient to fetch some data.  I've actually written a webcrawler in Tornado, so it can be used "headless".

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpclient

class Fetcher(object):
    def __init__(self, ioloop):
        self.ioloop = ioloop
        self.client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(io_loop=ioloop)

    def fetch(self, url):
        self.client.fetch(url, self.handle_response)

    @property
    def active(self):
        """True if there are active fetching happening"""

        return len(self.client.active) != 0

    def handle_response(self, response):
        if response.error:
            print "Error:", response.error
        else:
            print "Got %d bytes" % (len(response.body))

        if not self.active:
            self.ioloop.stop()

def main():
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.add_callback(scrapeEverything)
    ioloop.start()

def scrapeEverything():
    fetcher = Fetcher(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance())

    listOfIds = [23423, 52356, 63462, 34673, 67436]

    for id in listOfIds:
        fetcher.fetch("http://mydatasite.com/?data_id=%d" % id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Good answer. Tornado docs on HTTPClient are here http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html (as the OP couldn't find them).

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to alternatives to tornado (I assume you scrape using socket programming, instead of urllib2), you may be interested in [asyncoro](http://asyncoro.sourceforge.net), a framework for asynchronous, concurrent (and distributed, fault-tolerant) programming. Programming with asyncoro is very similar to that of threads, except for a few syntactic changes. Your problem can be implemented with asyncoro as:

```
import asyncoro, socket

def process(url, coro=None):
    # create asynchronous socket
    sock = asyncoro.AsynCoroSocket(socket.socket())
    # parse url to get host, port; prepare get_request
    yield sock.connect((host, port))
    yield sock.send(get_request)
    body = yield sock.recv()
    # ...
    # process body

for i in [23423, 52356, 63462, 34673, 67436]:
    asyncoro.Coro(process, "http://mydatasite.com/?data_id = %s" % i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try native solution that do not require any external library. For linux it is based on epoll and may look like [this](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/fippo/rkLqk). Usage example:

```py
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def sampleCallback(status, data, request):
    print 'fetched:', status, len(data)
    print data

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fetch(HttpRequest('google.com:80', 'GET', '/', None, sampleCallback))
```